# Laravel - How to get Row with 2 column?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to show a list of `materi` (table), based on 2 values from 2 columns.
and the column is :

kelas (from user table)
nama_mapel (from mapel table) but in materi is just "mapel" not nama_mapel.

**My StudentController :**

```
public function showMateriList($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $mapel = mataPelajaran::findOrFail($id);

    $materis = Materi::where('kelas', '=', Auth::user()->kelas)
                        ->orWhere('mapel', '=', $mapel->nama_mapel);

    return view('pages.student.materi.showMateriList', compact('user', 
    'mapel', 'materis'));
}
```

**My View:**

```
 @foreach ($materis->chunk(4) as $materi)
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Show List of Mapels -->
      @foreach($materi as $m)
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-info">
            <div class="inner">
                <h4>{{ $m->judul }}</h4>
                <br>
                <p style="line-height:0px;">{{ $m->mapel }}</p>
                <p>{{ $m->kelas }}</P>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="/Student/Materi/Single{{ $m->id }}" class="small- 
   box-footer">Lihat Materi Ini <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> 
  </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
      @endforeach
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

**My Route:**

```
Route::get('/Student/Materi/List/{id}', 
'StudentController@showMateriList')->middleware('role:Student');
```

I Have tried using that code, but the result is :

> Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::chunk(), 1 passed in E:\laravel-projects\laralearn\storage\framework\views\eaf6a642fcf11eb5ecd3b5d7ed076551ba24d459.php on line 26 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: You missed the get to execute the query `$materis = Materi::where('kelas', '=', Auth::user()->kelas) ->orWhere('mapel', '=', $mapel->nama_mapel)->get()`

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain more?

Comment: If you do `$materis = Materi::where('kelas', '=', Auth::user()->kelas) ->orWhere('mapel', '=', $mapel->nama_mapel);`, $materis will be a Query Builder object instead a collection (the result of the query). Append `->get()` to it, to execute the query

Comment: Oh ya,  I missed "->get() ;" its shown no error but its blank...

Comment: Looks like there are not records in materi table with that user->kelas or that mapel->nama_mapel.

Comment: OHHHH YAAA! Its Works! Thanks @porloscerrosΨ. ya, there are no record for mapel->nama_mapel... Thank You... 

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the query. You don't get or fetch the result.

Try this one instead:

```
$materis = Materi::where('kelas', '=', Auth::user()->kelas)
                   ->orWhere('mapel', '=', $mapel->nama_mapel)->get();
```

Hope it's working.